# Document create displayAnchors are being ignored

Tags: docusignapi

I am attempting to create a responsive signing envelope using the htmlDefinition property in a document.

I have tried v2 and v2.1 with the same code.

```
"documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "JVBERi0x...mCjIzMzMzCiUlRU9GCg==",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "htmlDefinition": {
                "displayAnchors": [
                    {
                        "caseSensitive": true,
                        "displaySettings": {
                            "display": "collapsed",
                            "displayLabel": "Person 1"
                        },
                        "endAnchor": "$$$$E1",
                        "removeEndAnchor": true,
                        "removeStartAnchor": true,
                        "startAnchor": "$$$$S1"
                    },
                    {
                        "caseSensitive": true,
                        "displaySettings": {
                            "display": "collapsed",
                            "displayLabel": "Person 2"
                        },
                        "endAnchor": "$$$$E2",
                        "removeEndAnchor": true,
                        "removeStartAnchor": true,
                        "startAnchor": "$$$$S2"
                    },
                    {
                        "caseSensitive": true,
                        "displaySettings": {
                            "display": "collapsed",
                            "displayLabel": "Person 3"
                        },
                        "endAnchor": "$$$$E3",
                        "removeEndAnchor": true,
                        "removeStartAnchor": true,
                        "startAnchor": "$$$$S3"
                    }
                ],
                "showMobileOptimizedToggle": "true",
                "source": "document"
            },
            "name": "HTML Test",
            "order": "1"
        }
```

The envelope is created with the document.  Tabs are correctly placed but no sections are created.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying out some of our new features. This capability being new it's not yet enabled in all of the demo accounts. If you want to send me a personal email to inbar.gazit@docusign.com and I can work with you to enable your account. 
We will have all accounts enabled for smart sections very soon so that won't be necessary in the future, you're just ahead of the curve!